# por que no se muestra el placeholder en mi textarea

Tags: html5

Este es mi archivo html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       
      <head>
           <!--aquí van los metadatos --> 
           <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ejemplo formulario atributos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ejemplo_form_atributos.css"/>º
      </head> 
      
      <body>
     <!--aquí va el contenido -->
     <h1>Ejemplo formulario atributos</h1>
      <form method="get"
       action="xxxx">
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos a rellenar por la administración</legend>
        <label>Nombre del curso</label>
        <input name="nombre_curso"
         value="Creación páginas web" readonly>
      <br/><br/>
        <label>Código del curso</label>
        <input name="código_curso"
         value="2015/F1710031" readonly>
      <br/>
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos personales</legend>
        <label>Nombre*</label>
        <input name="nombre_alum" maxlength=10 
         autofocus required/>
        <label>Apellidos*</label>
        <input name="apellidos_alum" maxlength=30 required />
      <br/><br/>
        <label>Documento*</label>
        <input name="documento" placeholder="escriba su DNI"
          required />
        <label>Edad*</label>
        <input name="edad" placeholder="Mayores de 18"
        <type="number min" min="18" required />
      <br/><br/>
        <label>Observaciones</label>
        <textarea  name="notas" rows=3 cols=20 
       placeholder="Si necesita, escriba aquí sus observaciones">
       </textarea></fieldset>
      <br/><br/>
       <button>Enviar</button>
      </form>
      </body>    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 18):

El problema es cómo está escrito el código del `textarea`. Tal y como está ahora hay espacios en blanco entre las etiquetas:

```html
                <textarea  name="notas" rows=3 cols=20 
            placeholder="Si necesita, escriba aquí sus observaciones">
            </textarea>
```

Los espacios en blanco y los saltos de línea delante de la etiqueta de cierre `</textarea>` importan porque se consideran parte del valor del campo. De hecho, si te fijas, puedes pulsar dentro del campo y verás que están ahí.

La solución es simple: haz que la etiqueta de cierre esté pegada a la etiqueta de apertura. Entonces no tendrás problemas con espacios en blanco o saltos de línea interpretándose como valor y el *placeholder* se mostrará sin problemas:

```html
                    <textarea  name="notas" rows=3 cols=20 
                placeholder="Si necesita, escriba aquí sus observaciones"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo esta bien desordenado, tienes muchas cosas que no cierran en donde deberia de ser.

Te puedo compartir una parte de mi codigo que realize para un formulario, yo estoy aprendiendo a usar bootstrap, te va a ayudar bastante.

```
                    <!-- <form role="form" class="content">
                        <div class="header">
                              <h3>ES MOMENTO DE PROGRAMAR UN CAMBIO</h3>
                              <p>Dejanos tus datos aqui</p>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group texto">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <input type="nombre" class="form-control info" id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu nombre">
                             </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="correo" class="form-control info" id="correo" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu correo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="telefono" class="form-control info" id="telefono" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu telefono">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <textarea class="form-control info" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="btn_select"> Acepto los terminos y condiciones
                                </label>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">ENVIAR</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </form> -->
```

solo es cuestion de orden tambien.